# Ansible Skip Host For a Specific Role

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

```
I have a hosts file that looks a bit different for prod and test and here they are:

# Contains the host mappings

[master]
local-machine ansible_host=192.168.0.201 host_alias=local-machine

[node]
n1.com ansible_host=192.168.0.202 host_alias=n1
n2.com ansible_host=192.168.0.203 host_alias=n2
#n3.com ansible_host=192.168.0.204 host_alias=n3

[k3s_cluster:children]
master
node

[all:vars]
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
```

The above is for the test environment and the below is for prod environment:

```
# Contains the host mappings

[master]
m1.com ansible_host=192.168.0.201 host_alias=m1

[node]
n1.com ansible_host=192.168.0.202 host_alias=n1
n2.com ansible_host=192.168.0.203 host_alias=n2
#n3.com ansible_host=192.168.0.104 host_alias=n3

[k3s_cluster:children]
master
node

[all:vars]
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
```

In my playbook, I have the following:

```
---

# K3s installation and set up
- name: "K3S SETUP: K3s download, install and setup"
  hosts: k3s_cluster
  gather_facts: yes
  become: yes
  roles:
    - {role: prereq, tags: ['host', 'k3s']}
    - {role: download, tags: ['host', 'k3s']}
    - {role: raspberrypi, tags: ['host', 'k3s']}

- hosts: master
  become: yes
  roles:
    - {role: k3s/master, tags: ['k3s', 'master']}

- hosts: node
  become: yes
  roles:
    - {role: k3s/node, tags: ['k3s', 'node']}
```

I want to now apply that role: raspberrypi on my master node only for my prod environment and I would like to skip that role for the master node when I run Ansible against the test hosts file. Any suggestions on how I could do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `when` conditions to your roles, so you could do something like this:

```
- name: "K3S SETUP: K3s download, install and setup"
  hosts: k3s_cluster
  gather_facts: true
  become: true
  roles:
    - role: prereq
      tags: ['host', 'k3s']
    - role: download
      tags: ['host', 'k3s']
    - role: raspberrypi
      tags: ['host', 'k3s']
      when: not skip_raspberrypi|default(false)
```

And then in your test inventory, set `skip_raspberrypi=true` for the master node:

```
hosts:
  master_node:
    skip_raspberrypi: true
```

If you're using an ini-style inventory:

```
master_node skip_raspberrypi=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***"Apply role *raspberrypi* on *master* node only for *prod* environment.***

A: There are more options. 1) Either use the special variable *inventory_file*, or 2) use the special variable *inventory_dir* and create variable *raspberrypi_skip_master* by the inventory plugin *ansible.builtin.constructed*.

1. Use the [special variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) *inventory_file*. For example, given the inventory files

```ini
shell> cat test
[master]
local-machine ansible_host=192.168.0.201 host_alias=local-machine

[node]
n1.com ansible_host=192.168.0.202 host_alias=n1
n2.com ansible_host=192.168.0.203 host_alias=n2
#n3.com ansible_host=192.168.0.204 host_alias=n3

[k3s_cluster:children]
master
node
```

```ini
shell> cat prod 
[master]
m1.com ansible_host=192.168.0.201 host_alias=m1

[node]
n1.com ansible_host=192.168.0.202 host_alias=n1
n2.com ansible_host=192.168.0.203 host_alias=n2
#n3.com ansible_host=192.168.0.104 host_alias=n3

[k3s_cluster:children]
master
node
```

Run the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: k3s_cluster
  roles:
    - role: prereq
    - role: download
    - role: raspberrypi
      when: not (inventory_hostname in groups.master and
                 inventory_file|basename != 'prod')
```

---

2. The next option is to create a variable *raspberrypi_skip_master* by the inventory plugin *ansible.builtin.constructed*. See

```bash
shell> ansible-doc -t inventory ansible.builtin.constructed
```

Create the inventory *prod*

```bash
shell> tree prod
prod/
├── 01-hosts
└── 02-constructed.yml

0 directories, 2 files
```

```ini
shell> cat prod/01-hosts 
[master]
m1.com ansible_host=192.168.0.201 host_alias=m1

[node]
n1.com ansible_host=192.168.0.202 host_alias=n1
n2.com ansible_host=192.168.0.203 host_alias=n2
#n3.com ansible_host=192.168.0.104 host_alias=n3

[k3s_cluster:children]
master
node
```

```yaml
shell> cat prod/02-constructed.yml 
plugin: ansible.builtin.constructed
strict: true
compose:
  raspberrypi_skip_master: inventory_dir|basename != 'prod' and
                           'master' in group_names
```

Create the inventory *test* (the files 02-constructed.yml are identical)

```bash
shell> tree test/
test/
├── 01-hosts
└── 02-constructed.yml

0 directories, 2 files
```

```ini
shell> cat test/01-hosts 
[master]
local-machine ansible_host=192.168.0.201 host_alias=local-machine

[node]
n1.com ansible_host=192.168.0.202 host_alias=n1
n2.com ansible_host=192.168.0.203 host_alias=n2
#n3.com ansible_host=192.168.0.204 host_alias=n3

[k3s_cluster:children]
master
node
```

```yaml
shell> cat test/02-constructed.yml 
plugin: ansible.builtin.constructed
strict: true
compose:
  raspberrypi_skip_master: inventory_dir|basename != 'prod' and
                           'master' in group_names
```

Run the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: k3s_cluster
  roles:
    - role: prereq
    - role: download
    - role: raspberrypi
      when: not raspberrypi_skip_master
```

Given the trivial roles

```yaml
shell> cat roles/*/tasks/main.yml
- debug:
    msg: Role download
- debug:
    msg: Role prereq
- debug:
    msg: Role raspberrypi
```

The inventory *prod* will run all roles

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i prod pb.yml 

PLAY [k3s_cluster] *******************************************************************************************************************

TASK [prereq : debug] ****************************************************************************************************************
ok: [m1.com] => 
  msg: Role prereq
ok: [n1.com] => 
  msg: Role prereq
ok: [n2.com] => 
  msg: Role prereq

TASK [download : debug] **************************************************************************************************************
ok: [m1.com] => 
  msg: Role download
ok: [n1.com] => 
  msg: Role download
ok: [n2.com] => 
  msg: Role download

TASK [raspberrypi : debug] ***********************************************************************************************************
ok: [m1.com] => 
  msg: Role raspberrypi
ok: [n1.com] => 
  msg: Role raspberrypi
ok: [n2.com] => 
  msg: Role raspberrypi

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************
m1.com: ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
n1.com: ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
n2.com: ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

The inventory *test* will skip the *master* group

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i test pb.yml 

PLAY [k3s_cluster] *******************************************************************************************************************

TASK [prereq : debug] ****************************************************************************************************************
ok: [local-machine] => 
  msg: Role prereq
ok: [n1.com] => 
  msg: Role prereq
ok: [n2.com] => 
  msg: Role prereq

TASK [download : debug] **************************************************************************************************************
ok: [local-machine] => 
  msg: Role download
ok: [n1.com] => 
  msg: Role download
ok: [n2.com] => 
  msg: Role download

TASK [raspberrypi : debug] ***********************************************************************************************************
skipping: [local-machine]
ok: [n1.com] => 
  msg: Role raspberrypi
ok: [n2.com] => 
  msg: Role raspberrypi

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************
local-machine: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0   
n1.com: ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
n2.com: ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```